# Allow add a tag as interesting at new tag pop

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, popups

Sometimes an user could want to add the tag to its list of interesting tags when it hovers over a tag showing the new popup. Would be easier just click on a link available on popup to add the tag as interesting. It's similar to Subscribe link.

A link to add the tag to its ignored list could be useful.

Comment: I thought this was what 'Subscribe' did at first. It's the behavior I'd prefer certainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe does this -- in addition to adding the email subscription, it is also added to your interesting tags.

Comment: I think most people don't want to be notified by email when they add it to their interesting section. I've been marking 15+ tags as "interesting", but I certainly won't subscribe to any of them :) Having an own button for marking it as interesting (and maybe showing the number of people having done so) would certainly be nice!

Comment: What Johannes said it's exactly what I'm thinking.

Comment: @johannes - I agree, it's a cool new feature but I don't want the emails either.