# Tag unsubscribe removes it from 'interesting tags'

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I've tried the new subscription feature on Java tag, but then decided I did not want to get another daily e-mail after all.

After I've hit **unsubscribe** the tag was also removed from my **Interesting Tags**.

Comment: Given that subscribing [adds a tag to your interesting tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74383/allow-add-a-tag-as-interesting-at-new-tag-pop/74395#74395), this might be `[status-bydesign]` (though even if it is, it's likely not the desirable behaviour).

Comment: @Tim: Surely since adding a tag to your interesting tags doesn't automatically subscribe you, this isn't by design.

Comment: @Jefromi That's true, but in this case the unsubscribe link was undoing all of the things that the subscribe link did (email + interesting tag), which may be expected. Based on Geoff's answer, it looks like they'll be separating the actions a bit, which makes more sense anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are adding a * next to the subscribers count which will allow you to favorite a tag - this will be disconnected from the current "subscribe" link which will opt you in for daily emails.  Expect this in the next build.